# Laravel Joining Tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm not sure if I can explain this right, but it's worth a shot, because I'm really stuck.

What I am trying to do is grab everything from the eventSchedule table that is matching the url id. In eventSchedule table I have created a column called eventSponsors which is a string that has the title to multiple sponsors. I am trying to have the selected eventSchedule pull back only the listed eventSchedule.eventSponosors from the Sponsors table. The issue I am having is that I have multiple sponsors for each eventSchedule and multiple Sponsors being resused in different eventSchedule. So the only common factor I can find between the two table is the sposnors title.

eventScheduleSeeder

```
array(
        'id' => '1', 
        'eventSponsors' => 'Enterade Hammer_Nutrition Trek_Bicycle_Store Marathon_High Jacksonville_Running_Company Country_Rocks_the_Beach'
      ),
```

sponsorsSeeder

```
 array(
            'id' => '7', 
            'title' => 'Hammer_Nutrition', 
            'src' => 'images/sponsors/hammer_logo.png', 
            'alt' => 'Sponsor - Hammer Nutrition', 
            'url' => 'http://www.hammernutrition.com/'
        ),
```

HTML

```
@foreach($eventDetails as $info)
 @foreach($eventSponsors as $sponsors)
<? if(strpos($info->eventSponsors, $sponsors->title) !== false){?>
   <p>{{$sponsors->src}}</p>
<?}?>
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The result I am getting back is just the src for the first title, Enterade. I read up on strpos() and I know it only finds the first occurrence or the last occurrence, but I am not sure how to have the string of titles find and pull back everything with the matching title.

Like I said I am not sure if I am explaining what I need right, but I am willing to anwser and explain in greater detail to help try and figure out this issue. I am new to Laravel and could really use the help. Thanks.

Comment: What gives `{{$info->eventSponsors}}` and `{{$sponsors->title}}` in the loop just before the if? Could you try with the `@if/@endif` syntax?

Comment: So you are saying to change my syntax to `@if(strpos($info->eventSponsors, $sponsors->title) !== false)<p>{{$sponsors->src}}</p>
@endif` I still get the same result of just `images/sponsors/enteradelogo.png` when I need to be having 6 in total returning.

Comment: Ok... And about my first question (checking contents of `$info->eventSponsors` & `$sponsors->title` right before the `if`)? Are those values looking as expected?

Comment: Yes, `$info->eventSponosors` is pulling back the string of all the titles for the selected event. And `$sponsors->title` is pulling back all the sponsor titles in the table.

Comment: Do you use `Eloquent` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I really understand your question, or why you aren't using relationships.... But I'm gonna try to answer

Just do something like this...

```
    $event = EventSchedule::find(1); //get first event

    $sponsors = explode(" ", $event->eventSponsors);

    $eventTitles = array();
    foreach($sponsors as $val){
      $eventTitles[] = Sponsors::where('title','=',$val)->get();
    }

    //Now your eventTitles array has all the associated sponsors for that event.
```

Or in your view....

```
     @foreach($event as $val)
     <?php $titles = explode(" ", $val->eventSponsors);
     foreach($titles as $val2){
      $info = Sponsor::where('title','=',$val2)->first();
      echo $info->title;
      echo "<img src='".$info->src."'>";
     }?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this actually helped!!! I just had to adjust some things.
`array('eventDetails'=>Raceschedule::where('id',Request::segment(2))->get())`

In my view
`<? $raceSponsors = explode(" ", $info->eventSponsors);                 foreach($raceSponsors as $val)
{
   $sponsorTitles = Sponsor::where('title','LIKE',$val)->get();
   foreach ($sponsorTitles as $val2) 
   {?>
     <img src="../{{$val2->src}}" alt="{{$val2->alt}}" title="{{$val2->alt}}" />
   <?}        
}?>`